# How to drop trailing zeros from decimal and format a currency using Python

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework

I try to drop trailing zeros from decimal and format a currency with this code

```
def dropzeros_with_comma(num):
    return "{:,}".format(num)
```

It works when num is 2220.80 it returns 2,220.8

but when num is 2220.00 it returns 2,220.0 I want just only 2,220

Could anyone please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a particular format for that; you can drop the ".0" manually:

```
def dropzeros_with_comma(num):
    s = "{:,}".format(num)
    if s.endswith(".0"):
        return s[:-2]
    else:
        return s
```

Comment: The `else:` is redundant.

Comment: Yeah, the `else` is unnecessary; it can be included for symmetry or omitted for brevity

Comment: Brevity is not the reason; it's to make sure the function always returns something.  Since your code finishes both branches with `return` that's logically covered, but a mod to the code could easily lose that property.  I would have used `s = s[:-2]` and let the single return statement handle both cases.

Comment: That works too; in a short function like this, any of these are fine. In a longer function, it'd probably be clearer whether it's a list of alternatives, a guard, or a modification of the value

Comment: Alternatively it is possible to use int(s) instead of s[:-2] as far as I can tell